# Font size is different on the Contents page

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, memoir

I use `memoir` class and got some problems with ToC. 
Chapter style defined as:

```
\font\robotoLarge="name:Roboto:protrusion=default;expansion=default;tlig;trep" at 24pt

\makechapterstyle{general}{
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vskip 30mm}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\hspace*{16mm}\robotoLarge{}##1\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1ex}}
\renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\hrule height 0.5mm\vskip 40pt}}\chapterstyle{general}
```

But when ToC is created, the chapter style is defferent: the font is smaller, the `\hrule` has no space before and sticks to letters. How can the style of ToC be fixed to be the same as my main chapterstyle?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! It would help if you posted a MWE (minimum working example), rather than some code snippets, that generates the problem behavior you're trying to get rid of.

Comment: You should use `fontspec` facilities for defining the "Roboto" font for usage in your document, not resorting to the `\font` primitive.

Comment: egreg, thanks. I will rewrite the code to use `fontspec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `toc` title is typeset using the part of the chapter style which is suitable for `un-numbered` pages. People often forget to add this part, see `\printchapternonum`. Also remember that the un-numbered part never issues `\afterchapternum` so it may be an idea to add this to `\printafternonum` (which is empty by default).

Since I have no idea what that font is about, please post a minimal example, and which engine you are using. This test using palatino, does not seem to have any differences between numbered and un numbered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\def\robotoLarge{\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ppl}\fontsize{24pt}{30pt}\bfseries}

\makechapterstyle{general}{
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vskip 30mm}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\hspace*{16mm}\robotoLarge{}##1\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{1ex}}
 \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\hrule height 0.5mm\vskip 40pt}}
\chapterstyle{general}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
%\chapter*{This is a test}
\chapter{This is a test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! `fontspec` and `\printafternonum` make everything working as it should.